# Como diminuir o tempo de compilação?

Tags: visual-studio, desempenho, compilação

Tenho uma *solution* com 20 projetos, e a maioria tem uma relação de dependência  um com o outro. O tempo de compilação demora bastante (6-8 minutos – pode parecer pouco, mas prejudica muito na hora de fazer testes), mesmo com alterações em só um dos projetos. A *solution* está em desenvolvimento, portanto, tem crescido bastante, o que me preocupa se esse tempo aumentar muito mais.

O projeto em que a compilação é a mais demorada é o que contém toda a parte visual WPF (*.xaml e *.xaml.cs)

- **Existe alguma maneira de diminuir esse tempo?**
- **O que costuma deixar o tempo de compilação muito demorado?**

---

**Info. adicional**

Windows 10 64 bits, i7 2.7GHz, 16 gb RAM. Utilizo o VS 2013.

Já testei em SSD e HDD, obtive resultados parecidos, nada gritante de diferença na demora do build. Já mudei também a versão do VS, testei com o VS2013, VS2015 e o VS2017 RC, o VS2013 é o que melhor roda minha *solution*.

Reitero que é sim um projeto grande, tenho mais de 200 `UserControls`/`Windows` WPF, o que acaba deixando o *build* do projeto só de telas (que já citei anteriormente) ser o mais demorado. (não que os outros não demorem!)

[image]

Já mudei várias vezes estas configurações, hoje utilizo o padrão, mas já tentei diversas coisas para tentar diminuir o tempo de compilação, não consegui muito resultado.

Comment: Eu tenho solutions com vários projetos também mas nunca vi nada assim. Qual a configuração da sua máquina?

Comment: @RicardoPontual São vinte projetos, porém são bem grandes. Acho que o grande problema é o WPF, posso estar errado. Uso um i7 2.7GHz com 16 GB de RAM. Meu SO é o Windows 10. Já testei a solution em diferentes máquinas e diferentes versões do VS, o mais performático é o VS 2013, mas mesmo assim, demora uns 6 minutos.

Comment: O build é feito localmente para a maquina do `tester` ou você usa um servidor de CI?

Comment: Localmente. @Intruso

Comment: Você está rodando com alguma configuração de compilação personalizada ou a padrão?

Comment: para uso corporativo (porque é caro, e usa várias/muitas maquinas) nada nelhor que Incredibuild

Comment: Oi @Vinicius, independente da linguagem eu costumo usar uma variável interna que chamo de User_Admin e seto como True para o caso de testes (inclusive). Ela permite que certos formulários/módulos sejam executados diretamente, ou seja, carrego parcialmente o que preciso para compilar (quando é o caso) e executar sem iniciar o sistema do zero e ativar tudo, Sei que não é a solução do teu problema, mas esta prática tem ajudado mesmo em casos sem compilação, onde segundos adicionais para testes interferem na produtividade da programação.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Passei a utilizar o Visual Studio 2017. O tempo de build caiu dos 8 minutos para 4 minutos em média. Resolveu para mim.

A parte visual ainda é a mais demorada na compilação. O teste que tinha feito no VS2017 ainda era na versão RC.

Saiba mais sobre o [**Visual Studio 2017**](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/).

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa primeiramente descobrir qual é o gargalo. Abra o gerenciador de tarefas enquanto faz o build veja qual hardware fica 100% de uso, provavelmente é a CPU. Desligar o Windows Defender ou qualquer outro anti-vírus é imprescindível pois eles são grandes vilões de performance. O seu hardware parece bom, SSD ajuda muito mas a placa mãe precisa sustentar a velocidade, verifique se na cópia de um arquivo grande(gigas) tem a velocidade sustentada a no mínimo 380MB/s, se não tiver sua placa mãe é um gargalo para o SSD. Verifique também se a opção AHCI está ligada no BIOS, isto ajuda na performance de disco. Eu trocaria este processador por um com clock mais alto, creio que você também  deva usar apenas 4 builds em paralelo pois i7 somente tem 4 núcleos apesar de ser 8 threads. Eu tenho um ótimo PC para poder testar o seu build se você se interessar é só me passar o projeto.